# push objects has multidimensional array

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs i have 2 objects like the below

[image]

i have merged both the objects by using angular.merge as shown below

[image]

i want to display output as

```
{
name:"sam"
gender:"male"
   relation:{
       father:true
       mother:true
      }


}
```

how can i achieve above result

Comment: Do something like this: `.push({relation: data});`

Comment: can u post a sample code ?? or refrence

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this.

```
var obj1={
  name:"sam",
  gender:"male"
};
var obj2={
  father:true,
  mother:true
};
obj1.relation=obj2
console.log(obj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply merge the two objects like this:

```
var person = {
  name:"sam",
  gender:"male"
}

var relation = {
  father:true,
  mother:true
}

var merged = angular.merge(person, {relation: relation});
```